# Counting number for duplicate in Sails js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, sails.js, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get counting number for duplicate in SailsJS + mongoDB.
Model is pretty simple:

```
attributes: {
    sub_id: {
        model: 'Submission'
    }
}
```

So, every row contains its id and reference to other table. I'm still new to waterline/Sails JS so I'm kinda lost how to count numbers for each unique sub_id (sub_id 5 has 3 rows, sub_id 9 has 10 rows, etc). In mysql, a query could something like this:

```
SELECT distinct(sub_id), count(id) FROM table group by sub_id
```

How could I translate this in Sails JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent for MongoDB is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). You need to access the native collection object to be able to use it:

```js
Model.native(function(err,collection) {

    collection.aggregate(
        [
            { "$group": {
                "_id": "$sub_id",
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }}
        ],
        function(err,results) {
            console.log( results );
        }
    );

]);
```

So [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is analogous to "GROUP BY", which is essentially another form of distinct in itself really. The [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator is basically "SUM", but when fed a constant value of `1` then this is the same as "COUNT".

Under native collections the methods conform to the node native driver spec, so all options to [`.aggregate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate) are shown there.

Also see the [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the documentation for other common translations.